# NextJS - How to add a parameter in the link of an image inside a loop

Tags: node.js, dictionary, next.js

my object movies.map not working images `{movie.poster_path}`

NextJs version: 6.1.1

Line

```
<img className="card-img-top" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185//{movie.poster_path}" alt={movie.title} />
```

[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dbLC.png)

Complete code

```
  <div className="row">
    {movies.results.map((movie) => (
      <div className="col-3">
        <div className="card" styles={{ width: '18rem' }}>
          <img className="card-img-top" src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185//{movie.poster_path}" alt={movie.title} />
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{movie.title}</h5>
            <p className="card-text">{movie.overview}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use string [concatenation](http://2ality.com/2011/10/string-concatenation.html) or [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) inside [expressions](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#javascript-expressions-as-props)

e.g.

```
src={"http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" + movie.poster_path}
```

or

```
src={`http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/${movie.poster_path}`}
```

Hope this helps.